# Majority Element Algorithm Time complexity

Tags: java, algorithm

need help to determine the time complexity for my solution to Majority Element

Problem Description
Task.

The goal of this code problem is to check whether an input sequence contains a majority element.
Input Format.

The first line contains an integer , the next one contains a sequence of  non-negative
integers 0, 1, . . . , −1.
Constraints.

1 ≤  ≤ 105
; 0 ≤  ≤ 109
for all 0 ≤  < .

Output Format.

Output 1 if the sequence contains an element that appears strictly more than /2 times,
and 0 otherwise.

Sample 1.

Input:
5

2 3 9 2 2

Output:

1

```
public class MajorityElement {

    private static int getMajorityElement( int count, int right) {

        //write your code here
        
        if ((float) count > (float) right / 2) {
            return 1;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FastScanner scanner = new FastScanner(System.in);

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int c = 0;

        int[] a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = scanner.nextInt();

            if (map.get(String.valueOf(a[i])) == null) {

                map.put(String.valueOf(a[i]), 1);
            } else {
                int count;

                count = map.get(String.valueOf(a[i])) + 1;
                map.put(String.valueOf(a[i]), count);
                if (c < count) {

                    c=count;
                }
            }
        }
        if (getMajorityElement( c, a.length) != -1) {
            System.out.println(1);
        } else {
            System.out.println(0);
        }
    }

    static class FastScanner {

        BufferedReader br;
        StringTokenizer st;

        FastScanner(InputStream stream) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String next() {
            while (st == null || !st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return st.nextToken();
        }

        int nextInt() {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the complexity is? Which part of your code is causing you doubt?

Comment: @tgdavies  I want to know if my solution Is more time-efficient compare to solutions online for example [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/majority-element/) which has the time complexity of n^2 and n log n and the most efficient one is n

Comment: What's your estimate of time complexity of the code you have written? If you are not confident that you are right, can you explain why?

Comment: @tgdavies I think the complexity is way less than n since the only computation done after the user has finished entering the data is to call the getMajorityElement function and it has no loops at all just a simple if statement but I'm not confident that I'm right since the most efficient solution I found online has the time complexity on n and I just started diving into algorithms and my experience is not that much.

Comment: Why the Hell don't you let the function getMajorityElement return 0 or 1 ?? Also note that the casts to float are superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of the function getMajorityElement is O(1), because you are doing a simple logic inside the function, but the complexity of the entire code is O(n) because you have a loop that runs n times.